# Set template for pages with a plugin

Tags: wordpress

Im looking for a plugin which lets me choose templates for my pages.

Currently, what im doing is i manually open up the page for which i want to set a template and choose one for this single page. I then have to do this again for all the other pages one by one.

Is there a plugin which lists all my pages and lets me easily choose a template for these pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is not such plugin because this feature is integrated in the wordpress core, http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/7/20222113055-orig.png

Comment: Heh, thank you i guess, shouldve figured that out on my own but still thanks alot